# Не могу декодировать ответ сервера, сжатый Brotli , как я понимаю

Tags: python, json, brotli

Отправляю запрос: https://tarkov-market.com/api/be/items?lang=ru&search=&tag=&sort=change24&sort_direction=desc&trader=&skip=20&limit=1

Заголовки ответов:

```
Cf-Cache-Status:DYNAMIC

Cf-Ray:85f15c904e665b66-VIE

Content-Encoding:br

Content-Type:application/json

Date:Mon, 04 Mar

2024 11:00:16 GMT

Nel:{"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}

Report-To:{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=GXUuCn8PzGNw5BEcunVOVYkU8aY55JGoibYYSPMbvP%2FeE2un1MWkmb1%2F0xxP4FKZkedI%2FbPl1O7NCLhMxmQxTFNfINW6XAFuE2hEnWz1kUflPARijTNx556Y2Vp3fPbzigQ6"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}

> Server:cloudflare

> Set-Cookie:HCLBSTICKY=a36e5887e3e480c7b14b65deb74f466e|ZeWpw|ZeWpw;
> path=/

> Set-Cookie:__cf_bm=PUZw3Sc3tLwvY._shB_3MZI7G8hOjNz7kLyO0uODVXI-1709550016-1.0.1.1-1goqlY1uA7VNwx9Jq5GwxDe5w.wspAasi78dKPjzGNEBZ9b6jDa1mobsI_Gj8BBcVAULmdzX.Ybz73EIJb4m.g;

path=/; expires=Mon, 04-Mar-24 11:30:16 GMT;

domain=.tarkov-market.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None

Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000 Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

В браузере отображается json ответ: ->

```json
{
    "result":"ok",
    "items":"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"
}
```

Но как я понимаю, это не Brotli, хотя написано Content-Encoding:br.

Помогите разобраться - как вынуть данные из этого ответа?

Пытаюсь с помощью Python'а раскодировать:

```
import brotli
response_server = '{"result":"ok","items":"JTVCJNjMkgTdCJTIydWl......."}'    # Сокращено
data_dict = eval(response_server)     # строку в словарь
data_items = data_dict['items']       # вынимаю значение ключа items

b_string = bytes(data_items, 'utf-8')  # иначе brotli будет ругаться что строка не байтовая

brotli.decompress(b_string)
```

Выдает ошибку:

> brotli.decompress(b_string)
> brotli.error: BrotliDecompress failed

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Браузер показывает уже распакованный ответ. Это JSON, как и написано в Content-Type.
В чём собственно проблема?

Comment: `items` похож на `base64`

Comment: Мне необходимо этот набор символов превратить в данные с которыми можно работать.
Возможно похож, но онлайн декодеры base64 выводят чушь при попытке декодирования, но спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Ещё раз — браузер уже распаковал бротли, забудьте про него. У вас в ответе пришли какие-то бинарные данные закодированные в base64. Как именно эти бинарные данные нужно интерпретировать зависит от приложения.

Comment: Нашел сайт с кучей декодоров "https://dencode.com/ru/"  -> закинул туда строку возвращаемую сервером (JTVCJNjMkgTdCJTIydWl.......) -> результат нулевой - подскажите, куда можно дальше двигаться, не хочется selenium использовать и листать весь список в 3000 позиций, а потом сохранять и распарсивать...

Comment: А как-то подсмотреть, как эти данные использует уже имеющийся код, которому эти данные передаются, никак нельзя?

Comment: Я только начинаю в Python, а там очень хитро все на Java-script

Comment: Сделал с помощью Selenium, но 8 минут на загрузку страницы с более чем 3000 товаров... Жесть! - очень нужен совет, что можно сделать с этим **items** ?